# Is it possible to track a specific folder on a remote with GIT?

Tags: git

I have a repository with one folder.

On my backup machine, this is just cached in another folder. 
On my project machine, this folder needs to exist in my home directory.

Of question is the version on my project machine home directory, which is currently not following the repository.
I can't just git init my home directory.

Short of .gitignoring everything but the folder in question, how can I/is it possible to set up HEAD to only track a single folder within my repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the repository into your home directory and symlink the backup folder from the git repository into your home directory.

`ln -s folder ~`

Edit:

Since you wanted to only track one folder, you could create a git repo in your home folder with a .gitignore containing the following

```
*
!/folder
```

Comment: Hah, I over complicated it. Didn't need to get it to track one folder. Just check out the entire repo and sym link the specific folder to home, obtain same results and don't need to hack git. Thanks.

I am however interested in whether it IS possible to track just one folder, though.